# The minimal partition of a triangle into pentagons

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

[The question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642102) about the existence of a cycle of a given length in a $3$-connected planar graph all faces of which are pentagonal, and also attempts to solve it led to the following problem.

> Insert into triangle a planar graph with pentagonal faces only, so
> that the degree of each of its vertices is not less than three.

This problem was solved [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370288).
The solution is obtained as follows. Consider a plane graph with $7$ vertices:

[image]

Each face in it is a pentagon.
We inscribe a dodecahedron graph into two of the three pentagons. As the result we obtain a graph with $37$ vertices all faces of which inside triangle are pentagons.
The degree of each vertex of this graph is at least $3$.
Denote this graph by $Q$.
We can see a plane image of graph $Q$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370288/finding-a-special-plane-graph-with-some-requirements-on-the-faces/370311#370311) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642102/what-is-the-range-of-possible-values-for-the-length-of-a-cycle-in-a-3-connected/4642158#4642158).

> **My question.** Is graph $Q$ minimal in the number of vertices among
> planar graphs in which there is a single triangular face and all other faces
> are pentagons and the degree of each vertex of this graph is at least
> $3$?

This question is posed purely out of curiosity and because I could neither prove the minimality of $Q$, nor construct a smaller graph with this property.

**Addendum.**

The answers of Parcly Taxel and student91 show that $37$ was too rough estimate for graph with specified property. The graph constructed by Parcly Taxel is symmetric and especially beautiful. But I am itching to clarify my question.

> **Clarifying Question.** After all, what is the minimal number of vertices in planar $3$-connected graphs all faces of which are pentagons except
> for exactly one triangular face.

As follows from Euler's formula for planar graphs, if a graph has a single triangular face and other faces are pentagons and three vertices are of degree $4$ and others are of degree $3$, then such graph must have $25$ vertices and Parcly Taxel constructed it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take the regular dodecahedron and open up the three faces around one vertex like petals of a flower. To each of the new degree-$2$ vertices attach a new edge and new vertex, then join these three latter new vertices by a triangle. The result is a $3$-connected partition of a triangle into $15$ pentagons using $25$ vertices.

[image]

This graph was found using the [plantri](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/plantri) command `plantri_ad -F3_1^1F5F6 16` followed by a little processing in Sage.

---

To show that this pentangulation is minimal, note that the dual of a $13$-pentagon example (the number of pentagons must be odd by Euler's polyhedron formula) would be a pure triangulation minus $2$ edges to leave $13$ vertices of degree $5$ and one of degree $3$. Consider all possible ways of adding these two edges:

- The extra edges are both incident to the degree-$3$ vertex. This leaves just degree-$5$ and $6$ vertices, and `plantri_ad -F5F6 14` will find all such triangulations. But the only graph returned is the Kleetope of the hexagonal antiprism, where the degree-$6$ vertices have no mutual neighbour that can correspond to the triangle face in the dual.
- One extra edge is incident, giving a degree-$4$ vertex and either of $\{6,6,6\}$ or $\{7,6\}$ (`plantri_ad -F4_1^1F5F6F7 14`) as the other non-degree-$5$ vertices before edge removal. There is only one graph in this class with $\{4,6,6,6\}$ as the "odd" vertex degrees, so the removed edges would have to form a perfect matching on these vertices. But the graph induced by the "odd" vertices has no perfect matching.
- The extra edges solely connect degree-$5$ vertices and leave "odd" degrees as $\{6,6,6,6\}$ and $\{7,6,6\}$ (`plantri_ad -F3_1^1F5F6F7 14`). There is only one graph in this class with $\{7,6,6\}$ as the "odd" degrees; the degree-$7$ vertex has to be adjacent to both degree-$6$ vertices in order to correspond to a triangle pentagulation, which is unfortunately not the case here (the degree-$7$ is only adjacent to one of the degree-$6$s).

We can exclude the $11$- and $9$-pentagon examples similarly, the latter of which is the absolute minimum from considerations of the sum of degrees of the pentangulation's vertices. Thus the graph above constitutes a minimal pentangulation of the triangle.

---

Again in a similar fashion, we can show that this partition of a square into $14$ pentagons is minimal:

[image]

Comment: It's a beautiful graph. 
I would like to draw your attention to the fact that I clarified my question.

Comment: @kabenyuk I just edited my answer to have a proof of minimality...

Comment: Yes, I'm already trying to understand your reasoning.

Comment: so unfortunate I can only give one upvote

Comment: @student91 you can give bounties to reward existing answers though.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  after several unsuccessful attempts to repeat your calculations with plantri I have to ask you a question. I couldn't find any keys like -f3_1^1 in the plantri manual. When I try to use such keys I get the message "_ is not permitted". Can you tell me where I can read about this?

Comment: @kabenyuk This is not plantri itself, this is an extended version of the program called plantri_ad which comes bundled with plantri proper. plantri_ad allows specifying degrees of vertices, and their number.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the following image:

[image: Image of Parcly Taxel]

That I retrieved from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4642191/583883), you see the left graph has a pentagonal envelope and a hexagonal interior and 31 vertices. The second graph has a hexagonal envelope and a triangle in the middle. When we put this second graph inside the hexagon of the first, we obtain a graph that you desire with only 34 vertices.

You should turn it "inside out" such that the pentagonal envelope becomes a center face and the triangle becomes the envelope if you want a triangle partition.